# AWK search header pattern and handle missing columns

Tags: awk

I have 2 CSV files, each having different columns, SOME of which are matching.

For example 1.csv:

```
"a1","a2","a3","a10"
12e23,123e123e,123e2e,3edwrf5
se1e,,1d431,345tg3
sw113,d134,d42334,3hy76j
21w32e,123e23,g546,67j67
```

2.csv:

```
"a4","a7","a2"
24ew2313e24,12retg3e123e,123e234r34re
se1e,1edertg4,1d423431
sw113,d13etg4,d4232334
```

I want to itterate through each of these files and execute AWK command to only output one of the columns, for example "a2".

Here is the command I am using:

```
for FILE in *.csv; do awk -F',' -v col='\"a2\"' 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==col){c=i;break}} print $c} NR>1{print $c}' $FILE; done
```

Now, this command works great in case both of my CSV files have the column. In case of "a2" I am getting this output:

```
"a2"
123e123e

d134
123e23
"a2"
123e234r34re
1d423431
d4232334
```

However if I'll be searching for column "a4", the output will be this:

```
"a1","a2","a3","a10"
12e23,123e123e,123e2e,3edwrf5
se1e,,1d431,345tg3
sw113,d134,d42334,3hy76j
21w32e,123e23,g546,67j67
"a4"
24ew2313e24
se1e
sw113
```

Note since 1.csv DOES NOT have the "a4", the output is the full contents of that CSV.

Question: how can I modify my AWK command to disregard any files where specific column name is missing? If the file does not have that column, I don't want to see it's contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print whichever fields are present in each file in whatever order you like using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    numOutFlds = split(cols,outFldNrs2Names)
}
FNR == 1 {
    delete fldNames2inFldNrs
    for ( inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++ ) {
        fldName = $inFldNr
        fldNames2inFldNrs[fldName] = inFldNr
    }
}
{
    out = sep = ""
    for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++ ) {
        fldName = outFldNrs2Names[outFldNr]
        if ( fldName in fldNames2inFldNrs ) {
            inFldNr = fldNames2inFldNrs[fldName]
            out = out sep $inFldNr
            sep = OFS
        }
    }
    if ( out != "" ) {
        print out
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v cols='"a2","a4","a99","a7","a3"' -f tst.awk 1.csv 2.csv
"a2","a3"
123e123e,123e2e
,1d431
d134,d42334
123e23,g546
"a2","a4","a7"
123e234r34re,24ew2313e24,12retg3e123e
1d423431,se1e,1edertg4
d4232334,sw113,d13etg4
```

Your specific cases would be:

```
$ awk -v cols='"a2"' -f tst.awk 1.csv 2.csv
"a2"
123e123e
d134
123e23
"a2"
123e234r34re
1d423431
d4232334
```

```
$ awk -v cols='"a4"' -f tst.awk 1.csv 2.csv
"a4"
24ew2313e24
se1e
sw113
```

Comment: Thank you Ed!! Your solution works for situation when I have small number of fields in CSVs, however if I have large number (more than 50-100), the script returns data from other fields, not the one I am searching for. Do you have any recommendation how to modify the script so it can handle CSVs with high number of columns?

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it has nothing to do with how many fields you have in your CSV, the posted script would continue to work if you have millions of fields in your CSV. There's something about the failing CSV that's different from the example you posted. Maybe commas within fields, or some headers not in quotes or newlines within fields, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nextfile` to skip a file.

```bash
awk -F, -v column=\"a2\" '
FNR == 1 {
  field = 0
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if ($i == column) {
      field = i
      break
    }
  }

  if (field == 0)
    nextfile
}
{
  print $field
}
' *.csv
```

Comment: Oguz, thank you!! The solution works for small number of columns in CSVs, however can you provide any recommendations what changes I can make to the script so it can handle CDVs with 50+ columns?

Comment: @user20221341 It can handle CSVs with 50+ columns already.